# Qu'en est-il vraiment de la forme appelée « interrogation indirecte » ?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

J'ai trouvé la terminologie «  proposition subordonnée interrogative partielle » appliquée à des phrases du type montré ci-dessous. ([Grammaire du Français • Terminologie grammaticale, p. 63](https://www.ac-paris.fr/portail/jcms/p2_2125483/livre-terminologie-grammaticale-web-1308526?details=true)

- Je demande à qui ce livre appartient. {phrase appelée « phrase  initiale » par la suite}

> (p. 63) l’interrogation porte sur le COI de « appartenir ». Le verbe appartenir se construit avec un COI (X appartient à Y) et l’interrogation porte bien sur la personne (Y) à laquelle appartient le livre (X).

Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec cette analyse et donc pas d'accord avec cette terminologie. Ma question porte sur mon analyse de la phrase, qui mène à ce désaccord ; suivent maintenant cette analyse et la question.

Imbriquons cette phrase dans une structure plus complexe.

- Lorsque  dans la classe je vois un livre qui traine je demande [à qui ce livre appartient].

Dans cette phrase est-ce qu'une interrogation quelconque a été formulée ? Non, c'est une assertion de ce qui est fait dans certaines circonstances, régulièrement, et certainement pas dans un cas particulier. Cette action répétée est une demande. De quelle demande s'agit-il ? C'est une demande de fourniture d'information, cette information étant *le nom du propriétaire d'un livre*. On a donc la reformulation suivante.

- Lorsque  dans la classe je vois un livre qui traine je demande [le nom du propriétaire de ce livre].

On voit selon ce contexte que « [à qui ce livre appartient] » est une [proposition relative substantive](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_relative#Relative_sans_ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent_(substantive)) ; il n'existe pas d'unité grammaticale autre qu'un groupe nominal pour la remplacer tout en conservant le sens qu'elle donne à la phrase. On peut réutiliser cette proposition dans des contextes où un verbe qui exprime l'action d'une requête ne se trouve pas, et il est encore plus évident qu'il ne sagit pas d'une question.

- [À qui ce livre appartient] n'est pas mon affaire et l'élève qui le possède sera puni pour l'avoir abandonné dans la classe.
- [Le nom du propriétaire de ce livre] n'est pas mon affaire et l'élève qui le possède sera puni pour l'avoir abandonné dans la classe.

En vertu de quoi  donnerait-on le sens de question à cette portion de phrase quand elle se trouve dans la phrase initiale et un autre sens quand elle se trouve dans la phrase qui précède ? Rien ne permet ce changement, dans les deux cas la signification est la même, celle d'un nom, le même nom (ou groupe nominal pour être précis).

En aucun cas la phrase initiale ne sera utilisée pour une interrogation ; on dit au plus « Je voudrais savoir [à qui ce livre appartient]. », mais cela ne dit pas dans l'absolu qu'on a demandé à qui que ce soit quoi que ce soit ; cette construction est donc divertie du sens fondamental quelle a, et cela, on le sait, par souci de politesse, mais rien de plus ; ce n'est pas une structure interrogative.

Il s'ensuit que la phrase initiale a bien la formulation suivante, puisque son imbrication ne change rien.

- Je demande [le nom du propriétaire de ce livre].

Il n'y a pas la moindre formulation d'une question dans cette phrase, et donc il n'y en pas non plus dans la phrase initiale.

La question est celle-ci ; à quel point dans l'analyse qui précède existe-t-il une divergence, un manque de bon sens, qui rendrait le raisonnement faux ? Quelle est, précisémment, la correction à apporter pour  déduire sans aucun doute qu'il s'agit d'interrogation comme il est prétendu dans la source citée ?

Comment: **Je demande *aux élèves* à qui le/ce livre appartient**.

Answer (score 1):

Mon interprétation, en lisant la définition, est que la phrase subordonnée provient d'une interrogation portant sur le verbe appartenir. Cette phrase pose une question de manière indirecte (la question est contenue dans subordonnée) grâce au verbe **demander**.

Le contexte peut (ou pas) renforcer l'attente d'une réponse. L'interrogation est en effet une interrogation **partielle** qui ne porte que sur une partie de la phrase, et c'est donc le contexte qui fixera l'"intensité" de l'interrogation. L'exemple ci-dessous exacerbe l'attente d'une réponse.

> A:  "A qui est ce livre ?"

> B: ...

> A: "Personne ne sait me dire à qui est ce livre?"

> B: ...

> Pour la troisième et dernière fois, je vous demande à qui ce livre appartient !

> B: A moi, Monsieur.

Dans la construction que vous proposez, vous introduisez une condition qui supprime l'attente immédiate d'une réponse à la question. L'interrogation devient donc latente et est moins évidente. Pour donner un exemple avec un autre type de phrase, si professeur dit à son élève:

> "Je vous ordonne de vous taire"

il attend une réaction immédiate. Par contre, s'il dit :

> "Je vous ordonne de vous taire lorsque le directeur est dans la pièce"

alors l'ordre est latent.

Pour revenir au sujet, il y a ici un doute entre :

- la proposition subordonnée interrogative partielle
  et
- la proposition relative substantive

Nous sommes d'accord que le contexte influence l'interrogation indirecte, qui n'est pas le vrai critère d'après moi car il porte effectivement à confusion. Le vrai critère est la nature du pronom : pronom interrogatif pour la proposition subordonnée interrogative partielle et pronom relatif pour la proposition relative substantive. Malheureusement, ces pronoms sont pour la plupart identiques. Il faut donc déconstruire la phrase pour bien les identifier.

En effet, sans la subordination on aurait:

> Je demande : "A qui cela appartient-il?" (interrogation)

qui donne donc

> Je demande à qui cela appartient (pronom interrogatif, donc subordonnée interrogative partielle). A noter qu'il s'agit d'un COD de "demande" malgré la préposition "à".

Ou bien

> Je lui donne. Il en a besoin.

qui devient

> Je donne à qui en a besoin. (pronom relatif, donc subordonnée relative substantive)

rem : Il n'est pas impossible de construire une phrase interrogative directe avec une proposition subordonnée interrogative :

> Est-ce que je vous ai demandé à qui appartenait ce livre ?

Comment: Ce que je demande est le point précis de l'analyse que je présente auquel se trouverait l'erreur de raisonnement, et ce qu'il faut penser pour se retrouver sur la voie qui permet la conclusion qu'il existe dans cette phrase une tournure interrogative fondamentale.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec cette réponse. Il faut, cependant, se dire: Oú est l'interrogation? Pour moi, c'est: "à qui appartient de livre". avec un ? sous-entendu.  Une subordonné. Et donc, "Je demande" c'est la principale, mais tronquée....

Comment: @Lambie Il faut, cependant, se **demander** où est …

Answer (score 1):

Voici ton erreur de raisonnement : Pour tenter de démontrer qu'une interrogation indirecte n'est pas une interrogation indirecte, tu remplaces cette interrogation par une proposition où l'interrogation est sous-entendue :

> Je demande ***à qui** ce livre appartient*.

> Je demande *[**quel est**] le nom du propriétaire de ce livre*.

Dans les deux cas, on peut difficilement contester le caractère interrogatif de la proposition subordonnée puisqu'elle suit la principale « **je demande** », verbe interrogateur s'il en est. Peu importe d'ailleurs la forme de la subordonnée, c'est le verbe introducteur qui détermine son caractère interrogatif. Ni un verbe, ni un pronom interrogatif ne sont nécessaires pour caractériser une interrogative. Par exemple « **Son nom ?** » est une proposition interrogative directe et averbale. Dans ta phrase, « **le nom du propriétaire de ce livre** » a simplement valeur de proposition interrogative indirecte averbale.

D'autre part, mais c'est accessoire ici, tu as aussi transformé la question, ce qui fait qu'il n'y a pas d'équivalence de sens stricte.

La réponse à la première question pourrait très bien être ***à ma sœur*** alors que cette réponse ne peut pas correspondre à la deuxième question.

<s>PS: L'expression "*Soi disante*" que tu utilises dans la question prend un trait d'union et est invariable (donc *la **soit-disant** interrogation indirecte*). Elle est encore parfois critiquée quand elle s'applique à quelque chose qui ne peut pas s'exprimer. Elle fait aussi soupçonner un parti-pris qui me fait penser que tu accepteras difficilement un avis contraire au tien.</s>

Comment: Ça n'est pas exact : « demander le nom… » est courant et « demander quel est le nom » ne l'est pas, mais tout à fait correct ; cependant le sens des deux ne fait qu'un. Pour s'en rendre compte Il n'y a qu'à consulter les listes qui correspondent à cet ngram : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=demander+le+nom%2Cdemander+quel+est+le+nom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdemander%20le%20nom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemander%20quel%20est%20le%20nom%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdemander%20le%20nom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemander%20quel%20est%20le%20nom%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Le sens d'une expression est défini par sa popularité ??

Comment: @LPH À l'infinitif sans doute. Mais je ne trouve pas perso. que conjugué comme dans ton exemple ce soit courant. Je ne me suis pas penché sur la question, c'est une simple réaction de ma part. Une réaction associée à l'ambiguité que je perçois et une impression qu'il « manque un morceau ».

Comment: @jlliagre Popularité ? Une diversion ne va rien résoudre, rien à voir avec le sens… c'est de l'information en plus, évidemment. Il n'en reste pas moins que avec ou sans « quel est » le sens est le même (deux constructions à valeur de substantif).

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis  Je suis  d'accord avec l'impression de « forme incomplète », mais les exemples abondent et l'usage préfère la forme raccourcie ; il suffit de passer en revue quelques références dans la page suivante pour voir que le sens est le même et que les cas « conjugués » sont nombreux : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lui%20demande%20son%20nom%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr. De toute façon cela n'a rien à voir avec la nature grammaticale des constructions ; peu usité ou non elle remplissent une place légitime dans la phrase.

Comment: @LPH Ah, j'avais mal lu ton premier *le sens des deux ne fait qu'un*. Oui, ils ont le même sens mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec ta dernière phrase, "deux constructions à valeur de substantif".  Non, *Quel est le nom du propriétaire du livre* et *le propriétaire du livre* ont tous deux valeur d'interrogations indirectes averbales dans ces phrases.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est à n'y plus rien comprendre ;  la reference que je cite dit ceci : « La proposition subordonnée interrogative partielle est l’équivalent syntaxique
d’un GN et peut avoir une fonction sujet ou COD »

Comment: Qu'est qui n'est pas clair ?